# Vertical align image inside of h-100 column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to vertical center an image in bootstrap 4. The nav bar should be a fixed height(100px) and the columns should also have a height of 100px, because they have a background.

I'm using `align-items-center` class but it doesn't seem to be working, the image stays at the top.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.navbar {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-color: #3366cc;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar sticky-top p-0">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192); height:100px;">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center h-100" style="width:100vw;">
      <div class="col-2 col-xxxl-1 h-100" style="background:white;">
        <img class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 100px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-xxxl-1 text-center" style="background: white;height: 100%;">
        <p class="no-wrap"><a href=""> Sign out</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for -

1) Removing `h-100` from the inner div does the fix aligns the content in the middle.

2) By changing the markup - added a div with class `col-8` which will serve as the blue middle section.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.navbar {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 100px;
}

.middle-nav {
  background-color: #3366cc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar sticky-top p-0">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192); height:100px;">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center" style="width:100vw;">
      <div class="col-2 col-xxxl-1 h-100" style="background: white;">

        <img class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 100px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 middle-nav"></div>
      <div class="col-2 col-xxxl-1 text-center" style="background: white;height: 100%;">
        <p class="no-wrap"><a href=""> Sign out</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The white backgrounds are there on purpose and would like to keep them. They need to be the full height of the row as the image on the left is also kind of blue.

Comment: @Rick Updated the snippet to meet your requirements. I hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You did not include what the `align-items-center` class is doing so it's hard to tell what might be happening.

Just adding the `align-items-center` class to the CSS with a `text-align: center;` can center the image.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.navbar {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-color: #3366cc;
  height: 100px;
}

.align-items-center {
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar sticky-top p-0">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192); height:100px;">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center h-100" style="width:100vw;">
      <div class="col-2 col-xxxl-1 h-100" style="background:white;">
        <img class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 100px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-xxxl-1 text-center" style="background: white;height: 100%;">
        <p class="no-wrap"><a href=""> Sign out</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry  I forgot to add the bootstrap css before. It's defined in there. Please check my edited question.